# How to process the URL in django

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

I have created a form where the user can select different dropdown. On the basis of user selection, it will create a URL on selecting the submit button and that URL is displayed in the page with the URL link. When a user clicks into it, it directs to related web pages.

But What I want is instead of a user clicking on URL, the related URL page should directly open when the user selects the select button.

Do we use ajax here to process the form?

I am not sure how to do it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In the view where you process your form, and where you're creating your url, instead of adding url to context just make a redirect to that new url.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it that way :

```
<select onchange="location = this.value;">
 <option value="/first_url/">first_url</option>
 <option value="/second_url/">second_url</option>
 <option value="/third_url/">third_url</option>
</select>
```